# NDSolve and DSolve

Tags: differential-equations

So basically I have a system of linear equations for springs im trying to solve. stiffSpr is nonlinear and linSpr is linear. But it keeps telling me that its expecting an equation and not true. I can't figure out why.

```
stiffSpr[k_, a_, x0_] := {x''[t] + k*x[t] + b*Abs[x'[t]]*x'[t] == 0, x[0] == x0, x'[0] == 0}

linSpr[k_, b_, x0_] := {x''[t] + k*x[t] + b*x'[t] == 0, x[0] == x0, x'[0] == 0}

A1 = NDSolve[stiffSpr[2.7, 1.1, 2], x[t], {t, 0, 10}]

B1 = DSolve[linSpr[2.7, 1.1, 2], x[t], t]
```

Comment: NDSolve demands that all the variables except the ones being solved for have been assigned some numeric value. So doing something like `b=3;` or some other constant before your `stiffSpr` definition will make the error message go away.

Comment: This question is a combination of simple and common mistakes: 1. The `a_` in `stiffSpr` should be `b_`; 2. One or more variables isn't cleared, `Clear[x, Derivative]` should resolve the problem, for more information check this post: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46214/1871

Answer (score 0):

Did you miss a space" "bewteen  k and x[t] for example?

```
stiffSpr[k_, a_, x0_] := {x''[t] + k x[t] + a Abs[x'[t]]*x'[t] == 0, 
x[0] == x0, x'[0] == 0}
linSpr[k_, b_, x0_] := {x''[t] + k x[t] + b x'[t] == 0, x[0] == x0, 
x'[0] == 0}

A1 = NDSolve[stiffSpr[2.7, 1.1, 2], x[t], {t, 0, 10}]

B1 = DSolve[linSpr[2.7, 1.1, 2], x[t], t]
```

Then the output for B1 :

```
{{x[t] -> 2. E^(-0.55 t) (1. Cos[1.54839 t] + 0.355209 Sin[1.54839 t])}}
```

Comment: I tried it myself, and it didn't work, and then I even copied it from the website and pasted it in. It didn't work and gave me the same error as before.

Comment: @Ossumdude Have you tried quitting the kernel and re-running? This sounds like you've got some lingering definitions that you need to clear.