# Clear assigned y'[x] from memory

Tags: differential-equations, syntax

If I, by mistake, write

Mathematica assigns $y'(x)=y(x)/5$ and I don't know how to clear that from memory (I had to restart Mathematica).

```
Clear[y,y',x]
```

did not help, but instead gave an error. What is the correct procedure to clear it from memory? TIA.

Comment: Do these answer your question? 1. [Why my differential equations become True?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46214/why-my-differential-equations-become-true) 2. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40314/1871

Comment: Use: ``Remove["`*"]``.