# How can I solve my second order ODE?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I am trying to solve

$\qquad y''(t)=\frac{1}{y(t)^3}-\Big(\frac{y(t)^4+1}{y(t)^5}\Big)y'(t)^2$

When I try to evaluate

```
Dsolve[{y''[t] == 1/y[t]^3 - ((y[t]^4 + 1)/y[t]^5)y'[t]^2}, y[t], t]
```

I just get back

```
Dsolve[{true}, y[t], t]
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: This "error" can be produced by inadvertently using the single = sign (`Set` command) instead of the double == sign (`Equal` command).  To clear the condition either evaluate `Remove[y]` or quit the kernel and then re-evaluate the `DSolve` expression.

Comment: it is `DSolve` and not `Dsolve`  screen shot  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hpyB.png)

Comment: If what you got back had `True` instead of `true`, then related: [(40314)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40314), [(46214)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46214)

Answer (score 1):

See this:

```
DSolve[{y''[t] == 1/y[t]^3 - ((y[t]^4 + 1)/y[t]^5) y'[t]^2}, y[t], t]

(*  {{y[t] -> 
   InverseFunction[
     Inactive[Integrate][-((Sqrt[2] E^(-(1/(4 K[1]^4))) K[1])/Sqrt[
        2 C[1] - ExpIntegralEi[-(1/(2 K[1]^4))]]), {K[1], 1, #1}] &][
    t + C[2]]}, {y[t] -> 
   InverseFunction[
     Inactive[Integrate][(Sqrt[2] E^(-(1/(4 K[2]^4))) K[2])/Sqrt[
       2 C[1] - ExpIntegralEi[-(1/(2 K[2]^4))]], {K[2], 1, #1}] &][
    t + C[2]]}}
*)
```

Have fun!