# boundary values with DSolve and plotting

Tags: differential-equations

I have been examining https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Books/8509/DifferentialEquationSolvingWithDSolve.pdf but cannot resolve my syntax issue

```
eqn = 0.1*y''[x] + 2 y'[x] + 2 y[x] == 0;
sol = DSolve[{eqn, y[0] == 0, y[1] == 1}, y[x], x]
```

but this yields

[image]

I am not sure why it is written "True, True" instead of applying the boundary condition.

Comment: try with clean kernel and it will work. You must have typed `y[1]=1` earlier but did not show that. This explains why you got `True`. Also, it is `Plot` and not `plot`

Comment: Always pay attention to the color of symbol. Your `y` is black, while it should be blue if it's _empty_. BTW, sometimes it's `Derivative` that's polluted: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40314/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46239/1871

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
eqn = 0.1*y''[x] + 2 y'[x] + 2 y[x] == 0;
sol = DSolve[{eqn, y[0] == 0, y[1] == 1}, y[x], x][[1, 1]]
Plot[y[x] /. sol, {x, -5, 5}]
```

works returning

```
(*  y[x] -> 2.87407 E^(-20. x) (-1. E^(1.05573 x) + 1. E^(18.9443 x))  *)
```

and the following plot:

[image]

However, I recommend you to use the integer numbers everywhere, where it is possible.
For example, using `y''[x]/10` instead of `0.1*y''[x]` you get this:

```
eqn = y''[x]/10 + 2 y'[x] + 2 y[x] == 0;
sol = DSolve[{eqn, y[0] == 0, y[1] == 1}, y[x], x][[1, 1]]
```

[image]

It is the same but looks much better. Besides, with the integer numbers, the result comes faster. The plot is, of course, the same as I displayed above.

Have fun!