# RUNGE-Kutta Code Mathematica

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to evaluate the DSolve and compare it to my Runge-Kutta code.

DSolve [{y[X]*y'[X] - 7 y[X] + 12 X == X^(3/2), y[0] == 1 }, y[X], X]

What is wrong with this equation?

Comment: f[y_, X_] := (7 y - 12 X + X^(3/2)) ((y)^-1) ;
N1 = 200;
h = (2.5 - 0)/N1;

w = Table [0, {m, 1, N1}];
w[[1]] = 1;
w
For [n = 2, n <= N1, n++,
 k1 = h*f[w[[n - 1]], h*(n - 1)];
 k2 = h * f[w[[n - 1]] + 1/2*k1, h*(n - 1) + h/2];
 k3 = h * f[w[[n - 1]] + 1/2*k2, h*(n - 1) + h/2];
 k4 = h *f[w[[n - 1]] + k3, n*h];
 w[[n]] = w[[n - 1]] + 1/6*(k1 + 2*k2 + 2 *k3 + 2*k4);]
w // N
DSolve [{y[X]*y'[X] - 7 y[X] + 12 X == X^(3/2), y[0] == 1 }, y[X], X]

Comment: Do you get any errors? It’s not clear what the problem is here.

Comment: DSolve::deqn: Equation or list of equations expected instead of True in the first argument {12 X-7 y[X]+y[X] (y^\[Prime])[X]==X^(3/2),True}.

Comment: Srijan, welcome to this forum. When you place a question and realize that forgot something, please edit the question instead of adding comments. Your pure code comment is confusing.

Comment: @SrijanBanjara That error message makes me think you previously entered `y[0] = 1` by mistake. `Clear[y]` or `y[0] =.` should fix that, but won't change the fact that there is likely no analytic solution.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40314/error-entering-equation-in-dsolve, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46214/why-my-differential-equations-become-true

Answer (score 2):

You can solve it numerically with NDSolve:

```
sol = NDSolve[{y[x]*y'[x] - 7 y[x] + 12 x == x^(3/2), y[0] == 1}, y[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

To visualize:

```
Plot[y[x] /. sol, {x, 0, 10}]
```